# How to replace a list of the old values with new ones in a string

Tags: elixir

Having a map of old_new values, what's the idiomatic way to replace those old_value with new_values in a string?

```
my_map = %{"old_value1": "new_value1", "old_value2": "new_value2"}
str = "some string .......old_value1 fafdsfd old_value2 faaaaaaa"
```

Since Elixir is immutable, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm assuming your map has String keys, not Atoms.)

If you're fine with running the replacements one by one, you can simply use `Enum.reduce` with `String.replace`:

```
iex(1)> my_map = %{"old_value1" => "new_value1", "old_value2" => "new_value2"}
%{"old_value1" => "new_value1", "old_value2" => "new_value2"}
iex(2)> str = "some string .......old_value1 fafdsfd old_value2 faaaaaaa"
"some string .......old_value1 fafdsfd old_value2 faaaaaaa"
iex(3)> Enum.reduce(my_map, str, fn {old, new}, str -> String.replace(str, old, new) end)
"some string .......new_value1 fafdsfd new_value2 faaaaaaa"
```

But if you want to run them in parallel, for performance or correctness (the previous solution will give a different result if any of the key of the map matches any other value), I would use something like this using `:binary.compile_pattern`, `:binary.match`, and pattern matching:

```
defmodule Main do
  def replace(string, map) do
    replace(string, map, :binary.compile_pattern(Map.keys(map)), "")
  end

  defp replace(string, map, pattern, acc) do
    case :binary.match(string, pattern) do
      {start, length} ->
        <<before::binary-size(start), match::binary-size(length), rest::binary>> = string
        replacement = map[match]
        replace(rest, map, pattern, acc <> before <> replacement)
      :nomatch ->
        acc <> string
    end
  end
end

my_map = %{"old_value1" => "new_value1", "old_value2" => "new_value2"}
str = "some string .......old_value1 fafdsfd old_value2 faaaaaaa"
IO.puts Main.replace(str, my_map)
```

Output:

```
some string .......new_value1 fafdsfd new_value2 faaaaaaa
```

Comment: what does this `<<before::binary-size(start), match::binary-size(length), rest::binary>>` do?

Comment: It splits the right hand side value into 3 binaries of sizes `start`, `length`, and whatever's left, and assigns them to `before`, `match`, and `rest` respectively.

Comment: but what's "<<" and ">>" and "::"?

Comment: `<< >>` is the binary syntax and `::` is part of binary pattern matching. There's some decent documentation about all of this on this page: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html.